# the DOM and XML functions for PHP5?

Tags: php, xml

i've read that you could use the DOMdocument class in php5 to manipulate XML documents. and also the XML functions.

where can i find documentation for the DOMdocument class with all its methods? and the same with XML functions?

are these the only things i need to learn when handling (creating and reading) xml documents with php5?

btw: there are xml_parser, xmlwriter, domxml, simplexml and so on built in into php5. which function set should i use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DOMDocument documentation](http://php.net/domdocument)

Comment: could u create a XML document with this class? or is it for reading a xml document? there is a tutorial with 2 titles "creating xml document with DOM" and "creating xml document with php". what is the difference? if im using, the DOMdocument class, im still creating it from php?